# MITK Build Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, cmake, mitk

I Build manually Qt 4.7.4 64bit and use cmake-gui in window7 make MITK source.

```
configure.exe -debug-and-release -qt-sql-sqlite -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-declarative -mp -nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake docs -opensource -platform win32-msvc2013
```

after make MITK, I build it use visual studio 2010 64bit

but there is some error like this

```
Error   91  error : could not find CMAKE_GENERATOR in Cache D:\MITK\MITK-superbuild-msvc2010_x64-03\CUSTOMBUILD

Error   89  error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   151
```

what can I do for solve this problem?

Comment: configure.exe -debug-and-release -qt-sql-sqlite -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-declarative -mp -nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake docs -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010

Comment: I don't know the software you are trying to use, but make sure you follow carefully this http://docs.mitk.org/2014.10/BuildInstructionsPage.html

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Those two links were very helpful:

https://www.mail-archive.com/mitk-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06034.html

http://sourceforge.net/p/mitk/mailman/message/34233529/

Firstly I downloaded patch.exe from gnuwin32 site. Then I added path to it in system variables.

And using CMake I builded MITK from source file:
MITK-2015.05.0-src-win.zip

During all procedures I blocked my antivirus. Now it's working fine.